# Partial Function Evaluation

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, functional-style

How can I evaluate only part of a stack of function calls?

In particular, given `f[x_,y_,z_]=x+y+z;`, say, I'd like to define a function `g[x:{_,_,_}]` that returns `f[x[[1]],x[[2]],x[[3]]]`, with the *index* calls evaluated but the overall *function* wrapper frozen.

Things I've tried: `HoldFirst` and `/._->_` operators, `Unevaluated` and the same, `/.List->Unevaluated@*f`. All of those end up with some variation on the evaluation of `f[x,y,z]`, which is then sometimes uselessly put on `Hold`.

To clarify - the use case here is comparing the unevaluated `f[x,y]` with an attempt at evaluating `f[x,y]`, to see if `f[x,y]` is meaningfully defined.

Comment: How about: `g[x : {_, _, _}] := Inactive[f][x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[3]]]`

Comment: ... or `g[x : {_, _, _}] := Defer[f][x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[3]]]`?

Comment: I /believe/ those will both result in an output with a wrapper, the way Hold does. It's not impossible I could work around that, but ideally I'd find a more elegant solution.

Comment: So let me ask: why do you want to define `f` if you don't want that definition to be used? If you never define `f`, you immediately get what you want, and you can do `expr /. f -> whatever` when you want to give meaning to `f`.

Comment: I think that @MariusLadegårdMeyer has the best solution for you. What you want seems contradictory: you want `f` to be unevaluated, and *the way that you delay evaluation* of an expression in *Mathematica* is via `Hold`, `Defer`, or `Inactivate` (the last is my preference), but you don't want the wrapper. There's no way to do this *unless* what you really want is for it to *display* as `f[ stuff ]`, in which case there's a solution. One possibility is to use `HoldForm`, which displays without a wrapper. Please clarify, and explain your use case a little more.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just deconstruct the argument in the pattern without using `Index` at all?

`g[{x1_,x2_,x3_}]:=f[x1,x2,x3]`

Comment: Because that will return the result of `f[x1,x2,x3]` - in this case `x1+x2+x3` - not the unevaluated expression `f[x1,x2,x3]`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `Inactive` and `Activate`.

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z

v = {4, 5, 6};
```

`Inactivate` only `f` with `Inactive` and allow `v` to resolve. Then `Activate` the result for the answer.

```
fv = Inactive[f][Sequence @@ v]

Activate[fv]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was my comment above but apparently the OP does not like this approach. I'm curious what the OP intends to do with this function,

Comment: @RunnyKine Ah, I see that.  Don't know how I missed it.